# java fileIO runtime error

Tags: java, file, file-io, runtime-error

## Information:

so i made a simple class that saves the highscores of a certain tetris game.

i need the file to be accessable when my whole game is achrived as a .JAR, so i need to make the file location external.

so now i use the "c://" loctaion cuase i'm certain all computers have that. But i'm not certain all computers have the LineHighscores.txt and TimeHighscores.txt files, so they need to be created.

## Question:

whenever i run my code i get an error:

```
  c:/TimeHighscores.txt
  c:/TimeHighscores.txt
  dec 19, 2012 2:26:35 AM tetris.FileIO loadHighscores
  SEVERE: null
  java.io.IOException: Toegang geweigerd
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:947)
at tetris.FileIO.loadHighscores(FileIO.java:75)
at tetris.FileIO.getTimeScores(FileIO.java:37)
at tetris.HighScores.<init>(HighScores.java:41)
at tetris.Menu$2.actionPerformed(Menu.java:75)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased
            (BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege
            (ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege
            (ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege
            (ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters
            (EventDispatchThread.java:244)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy
            (EventDispatchThread.java:151)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)

    java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\TimeHighscores.txt 
   (Het systeem kan het    opgegeven bestand niet vinden)
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at tetris.FileIO.loadHighscores(FileIO.java:84)
at tetris.FileIO.getTimeScores(FileIO.java:37)
at tetris.HighScores.<init>(HighScores.java:41)
at tetris.Menu$2.actionPerformed(Menu.java:75)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased
           (BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege
              (ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege
              (ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege
              (ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters
              (EventDispatchThread.java:244)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter
              (EventDispatchThread.java:163)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy
               (EventDispatchThread.java:151)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

## Code:

```
   public class FileIO   {
private File file;
private Scanner filescScanner, lineScanner;
private PrintWriter fileWriter;
private String[][] data;
static final String lineHighscoreTXT = "c://LineHighscores.txt", timeHighscoreTXT = "c://TimeHighscores.txt";


public FileIO () {
    data = new String[100][2];
}
public String[][] getLineScores(){
    System.out.println(lineHighscoreTXT);
    return this.loadHighscores(lineHighscoreTXT);
}
public String[][] getTimeScores(){
    System.out.println(timeHighscoreTXT);
    return this.loadHighscores(timeHighscoreTXT);
}

public void setLineScores( String name,String lines ){
    boolean found= false;
    data = this.getLineScores();
    for(int i = 0; i<data.length && !found ; i++){
        if(data[i][0] == null || "Niemand".equals(data[i][0])){
            data[i][0]=name;
            data[i][1]=lines;
            found=true;
        }

    }
    this.saveHighscores(lineHighscoreTXT,data);
}
public void setTimeScores(String time, String name){
    boolean found= false;
    data = this.getLineScores();
    for(int i = 0; i<data.length && !found ; i++){
        if(data[i][0] == null || "Niemand".equals(data[i][0])){
            data[i][0]=name;
            data[i][1]=time;
            found=true;
        }

    }
    this.saveHighscores(timeHighscoreTXT,data);
}

private String[][] loadHighscores( String fileLocation){

int x=0;
String test = "";
System.out.println(fileLocation.toString());
File file = new File(fileLocation);
if (!file.exists()){
    try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FileIO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
try{
    filescScanner = new Scanner(file);}
catch(Exception ioe){System.err.println(ioe);}

   if (filescScanner.hasNext()){


        while(filescScanner.hasNextLine()&& x<100) {

            lineScanner = new Scanner(filescScanner.nextLine());
            lineScanner.useDelimiter("-/-");


            data[x][0]=lineScanner.next();//name    
            data[x][1]=lineScanner.next();//data   
            x++;

        }
        lineScanner.close();
        filescScanner.close();
   }
   else{
       data[0][0] = "Niemand";
       data[0][1] = "0";
   }
    return data;

}
private void saveHighscores( String fileLocation, String[][] data){
    int x=0;
        file = new File(fileLocation);  
        if (!file.exists()){try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FileIO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
  }
    try {
        fileWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileIO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    if(data.length>x){
        while(data.length>x && data[x][0] != null ){
            fileWriter.println(data[x][0]+"-/-"+data[x][1]);
            x++;
        }
        fileWriter.close();
    }
}



 public static void main(String[] args){
    FileIO file = new FileIO();
    file.setLineScores("55555555", "KoenKevin");      
}

 }
```

Comment: 1. You shouldn't be creating files in the root directory of C:/; create it in the user's home directory (e.g. /Users/<name>) instead. 
2. (in `loadHighScores()`) Why are you continuing to scan data even if creating the Scanner failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand dutch, but I'm assuming this means "Access denied" ?

java.io.IOException: Toegang geweigerd

If so, this could be caused by Windows restricting file write into C:\ for security purpose.

You have to either write to other location, or run your application as administrator

Comment: +1 for learning dutch.  I lost it when I read that.  Your correct, just converted it with http://translation.babylon.com/dutch/to-english/

Comment: @Kevin Bowersox, gerrytan is correct. I recently made an app which deletes empty directories present, but I couldn't set the path to C:\ and cleanse the entire drive because of user permissions. You need to run the program as admin.

Trivia : Only RW options are disabled for users without admin privileges in the C:\ drive. You can still directory traverse.